# display icon with respective file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview, icons

Ok this is something new to me....

I have a gridview control which is displaying the files and directory names in one column.

Now i want to display the file icon of that particular file in the other column...

eg test.txt will have a different icon form image1.jpg and here.xsl

i have found two examples but don't kno if they will work or not....

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/AssociatedIconsImage.aspx

or

http://forums.asp.net/t/90921.aspx

how to incorporate this with my gridview..?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found a source that should be useful for you (and with a simple google query btw.): [Getting Associated Icons Using C#](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/icons/article.php/c4261/)
.

As far as I know, there's no other way than using the shell32 library via interop, as used in the given example.

Comment: yes i did my research also.. and i read shell32 concept also...
i found two examples... can u have a look if these are any better... 

http://forums.asp.net/t/90921.aspx and

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/AssociatedIconsImage.aspx

Comment: The example on CodeProject looks the most clear to me, however, caching icons as files might be a bad idea (what happens when your file associations change?). Caching an icon during the execution of your program might be fine though.

As I can see, both examples still use the interop/shell32 way, and albeit with some different code to render the icons, it is still with the same basics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a managed way to this... there very well could be, but the unmanaged way to get this would be to use PInvoke to call SHGetFileInfo.  [There is sample code on PInvoke.Net which should get you most of the way there.](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHGetFileInfo)